# Why do I get a list assignment index out of range when i already have the data?

Tags: python

So im making an address book (im new to python and programming in genreal) and it says that "list assignment index out of range" when i have added my so called range and here is my coding for modifying contacts:

```
def modifyContacts():
    contactToEdit = int(input("What contact do you want to edit? Choose a number."))
    Contact = ContactList[contactToEdit - 1]
    print(Contact[0] , Contact[1] , Contact[2])

    range(3) == [0, 1, 2]

    print("If you want to edit, press 1 : ")
    print("If you dont want to edit, press 2: ")

    toEdit = input("")
    if toEdit == "1":
        ContactList[0] = input(' Enter the new name of the contact: ')
        ContactList[1] = input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')
        ContactList[2] = input(' Enter the new e-mail of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')
    elif toEdit == "2":
        print("You can choose to do something else.")
    else:
        print("Not a valid option.")
```

I get that the range isn't enought at "ContactList[1] = input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')".

What am i supposed to do?

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You need to show the full error. Where is it happening?

Comment: You need to show us your `ContactList` definition. Create a [mcve]

Comment: Unrelated, but I wonder what you think `range(3) == [0, 1, 2]` is doing

Comment: @DeepSpace Wow! I too wonder.

Comment: @DeepSpace i literally dont know, what else am i supposed to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's happening at : ContactList[1] = input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')"

Comment: @cricket_007 ill add my full list in a seperate comment

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielRoseman has stated showing the instance where you define ContanctList would help, but it seems you're defining the list and then trying to assign values to non-existent ranges. From the code you've shown, you can try:

```
ContactList.append(input(' Enter the new name of the contact: '))
ContactList.append(input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')) 
ContactList.append(input(' Enter the new e-mail of ' + ContactList[0] + ': '))
```

instead of this:

```
ContactList[0] = input(' Enter the new name of the contact: ')
ContactList[1] = input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')
ContactList[2] = input(' Enter the new e-mail of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')
```

That should fix the error with the code you already have. Append will add the value to the end of the list even without the defined range.

Alternatively you can define the values [0,1,2] on your definition of ContactList but again not sure how you're defining it.

Comment: thank you so much! ill try and see how it is, the only definition i have for ContactList is  this: ContactList = ([])

Comment: Try ContactList = [] instead of using parenthesis. Empty paranthesis makes ContactList a tuple, brackets make it a list.

Comment: still the same, with my method it says that the list is out of range and with your method it says "Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"

Comment: Use your method and define ContactList = list(range(3))

Comment: Or use the method I gave you and change ContactList[0] to str(ContactList[0]) inside the inputs. That will change the data type into a string.

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time helping me, but it caused other problems in other places ://

Comment: <input(' Enter the new address of ' + ContactList[0] + ': ')> to <input(' Enter the new address of ' + str(ContactList[0]) + ': ')>. Same thing for the email.

Comment: omg thank you it worked!! I just have a question, it resulted in me having two contacts : [['Lisa', 'Pisa', 'lisa@gmail.com'], 'Liam', 'Ibiza', 'liam@gmail.com'] , how am i supposed to actually modify the current information and not add?

Comment: excuse me for asking you again, but i still haven't figured it out and im wondering if you have any idea of how to fix it? Because it appears like its 2 different contacts and when i browse it in a list it looks like this : 1:['Lisa', 'Pisa', 'lisa@gmail.com'] , 2: Liam 3: Ibiza 4: liam@gmail.com , but i obviously dont want it like that, it was supposed to modify not add and in that way

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Well that's what append does it just adds a new item to the end of the list. You could add an if statement where it only appends when the indexes are none existent and does what you implemented at first if they do exist. It's a whole other question of itself, I recommend going through the docs in python.org to get a better sense of what tools you have and what solutions you could implement.

Comment: thank you, i definitely will! But could you help me with the if statement, how do i code it to do it in the way i desired to make it, in other words, modify the current contact and not add?